# How to produce multiple modes in Python?

Tags: python, mode

Basically I just need to figure out how to produce modes (numbers occurring most frequently) from a list in Python, whether or not that list has multiple modes?

Something like this:

```
def print_mode (thelist):
  counts = {}
  for item in thelist:
    counts [item] = counts.get (item, 0) + 1
  maxcount = 0
  maxitem = None
  for k, v in counts.items ():
    if v > maxcount:
      maxitem = k
      maxcount = v
  if maxcount == 1:
    print "All values only appear once"
  if counts.values().count (maxcount) > 1:
    print "List has multiple modes"
  else:
    print "Mode of list:", maxitem
```

But instead of returning strings in the "All values only appear once," or "list has multiple modes," I would want it to return the actual integers that it's referencing?

Comment: You want to start with this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/16363

Comment: Ahh, no, I've already seen that. I need something that produces the modes and only the modes, not the rest of the integers and how often they appear?

Comment: so you just want to return the frequencies of the elements in a list

Comment: @hayleyelisa Then just take the one with the highest count

Comment: No, I need it to return multiple modes if there is more than one mode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a `Counter`, then pick off the most common elements:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

l = [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6]

# group most_common output by frequency
freqs = groupby(Counter(l).most_common(), lambda x:x[1])
# pick off the first group (highest frequency)
print([val for val,count in next(freqs)[1]])
# prints [3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: I get this error:
'itertools.groupby' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 1):

```
def mode(arr):

if len(arr) == 0:
    return []

frequencies = {}

for num in arr:
    frequencies[num] = frequencies.get(num,0) + 1

mode = max([value for value in frequencies.values()])

modes = []

for key in frequencies.keys():
    if frequencies[key] == mode:
        modes.append(key)

return modes
```

This code can tackle with any list. Make sure, elements of the list are numbers.

Comment: Please make sure to explain **why** your answer works and what issues it fixes.

Answer (score 0):

new in python 3.8's statistics module there is a function for that:

```
import statistics as s
print("mode(s): ",s.multimode([1,1,2,2]))
```

output: mode(s):  [1, 2]